# Spark streaming - Does reduceByKeyAndWindow() use constant memory?

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, spark-streaming

I'm playing with the idea of having long-running aggregations (possibly a one day window).  I realize other solutions on this site say that you should use batch processing for this.

I'm specifically interested in understanding this function though.  It sounds like it would use constant space to do an aggregation over the window, one interval at a time.  If that is true, it sounds like a day-long aggregation would be possible-viable (especially since it uses check-pointing in case of failure).

**Does anyone know if this is the case?**

This function is documented as: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-programming-guide.html

> A more efficient version of the above reduceByKeyAndWindow() where the reduce value of each window is calculated incrementally using the reduce values of the previous window. This is done by reducing the new data that enters the sliding window, and “inverse reducing” the old data that leaves the window. An example would be that of “adding” and “subtracting” counts of keys as the window slides. However, it is applicable only to “invertible reduce functions”, that is, those reduce functions which have a corresponding “inverse reduce” function (taken as parameter invFunc). Like in reduceByKeyAndWindow, the number of reduce tasks is configurable through an optional argument. Note that checkpointing must be enabled for using this operation.

Comment: Your aggregations require tumbling windows? (1 day every day) or sliding windows (the last day each 10 minutes, for example) ?

Comment: Didn't see this until now; it would be "tumbling" which I haven't heard of before :).  But I think I got my answer anyway.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching this on the MapR forums, it seems that it would definitely use a constant level of memory, making a daily window possible assuming you can fit one day of data in your allocated resources.

The two downsides are that:

1. Doing a daily aggregation may only take 20 minutes.  Doing a window over a day means that you're using all those cluster resources permanently rather than just for 20 minutes a day.  So, stand-alone batch aggregations are far more resource efficient.
2. Its hard to deal with late data when you're streaming exactly over a day. If your data is tagged with dates, then you need to wait till all your data arrives.  A 1 day window in streaming would only be good if you were literally just doing an analysis of the last 24 hours of data regardless of its content.